# what does (new String(“foo”) == new String(“foo”)) return in java , can you explain

Tags: java, string

if already one foo is present in heap , will it create new foo again in heap?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: I thought that `===` was not a valid Java operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a new Object will create in heap java Because you have create a new Object of String using new keyword

Comment: so that means technically two same foo will exist in heap ?

Comment: Yes both are exist in Heap